# How to know if the terminal understands '\033[2J\033[H'?

Tags: terminal

I would like to clear the screen, but only if it is possible. On most terminals this can be done with the escape sequence `\033[2J\033[H`. But not all terminals understand this. How to know, if the terminal understands the sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what the termcap or terminfo databases are for.

```
tput clear
```

Will look up in those databases the correct escape sequence for the `clear` capability  for the terminal or terminal emulator whose name is stored in `$TERM`.

[`tput` is a standard command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/tput.html), but the names of the capabilities are not specified by the standard except for a very few which luckily here happens to include `clear`¹.

Most systems also have a `clear` command even if that's not  a standard one which would do the same.

The  `tcsh` shell has builtin support for querying the `termcap` database with its `echotc` builtin, where the name of the corresponding capability is `cl`:

```
echotc cl
```

The `zsh` shell also has `echotc` as well as `echoti` for terminfo (both in the `zsh/terminfo` module, automatically loaded when you run `echotc`/`echoti` or access `$terminfo`):

```
echoti clear
```

There, the `$terminfo` associative array maps capabilities to the corresponding escape sequence (only useful for the ones that don't take parameters), so you can also do:

```
print -rn -- $terminfo[clear]
```

Most other languages (if not shells) will have interfaces to those databases (see libtinfo and higher level ncurses in C, `Term::Cap` or `Curses` in perl, `curses` and `notcurses` in python...

See [`man 5 terminfo`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html) for details on the terminfo database, and [there](https://www.invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html) for the HTMLified source of that database as maintained by [@ThomasDickey](/users/105132) (who also maintains ncurses and xterm and many other terminal-related applications) with plenty of useful information about the history of capabilities supported by various terminals or terminal emulators in comments.

---

<sup>¹ Though only in the `POSIX` locale so strictly speaking, POSIXly, you'd need `LC_ALL=POSIX tput clear` even if I don't expect that to be needed anywhere.</sup>