# How does `tput` detect color support

Tags: bash, shell, tput, terminfo, ansi

I am trying to make my shell script supporting as much terminals as possible, that is, adding ANSI colors, bold and dim only when supported. However, I want to detect the number of colors supported. We can use `tput colors`.

However, I find that some systems that are stripped down to minimal does not have it installed. So, I want to implement it in shell.

How does `tput colors` work? Any equivalent of `tput colors` with POSIX commands? Please help and answer.

Comment: A similar question posted today: [How to know if the terminal understands '\033\[2J\033\[H'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/730751)

Comment: *minimal systems* won't have bash either.

Comment: Definition of "minimal": https://www.suse.com/suse-defines/definition/minimal-operating-system/

Comment: Even many full blown operating systems won't have bash either. bash is the GNU shell, it's only used on GNU systems and a few non-GNU ones.

Comment: I think we are off topic debating whether Bash is installed on different operating systems XD... Lets remove these comments.

Comment: The point is that asking for a solution that works on any system is incompatible with using the bash tag as you do here. You'd need to clarify what sort of *minimal system* you're talking about. Is it just that JeOS you're refering to in a previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

`tput` queries the termcap or terminfo database based for the terminal whose name is stored in `$TERM`.

[`tput` is a standard command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/tput.html), but the names of the capabilities except for `clear`, `init` and `reset` (in the POSIX locale only) are not specified.

If some systems don't have `tput`, they likely don't have a terminfo or termcap database either.

Also beware that terminal names are not standardised.

For instance, there are many terminals that set `$TERM` to `xterm` even though they don't implement the `xterm` API fully or properly, and there are many versions of `xterm`, and `xterm` can be compiled or configured with support for different numbers of colours with that not being always reflected in the value of `$TERM`, not to mention that the shades of the various colours even for those that use the same escape sequences vary from one terminal to the next, so it's not an exact science.

On systems that don't have terminfo/termcap databases, you'd have to ship your own database (maybe a subset with the most commonly used terminals, and only the capabilities of interest) and implement a way to query it from your script.

At the very least, that could be just a big case construct:

```
case $TERM in
  ( fbterm )
     colors=256
     fg_color() { printf '\33[1;%sd}' "$1"; }
     ;;
  ( *256color* | alacritty | i[tT]erm* )
     colors=256
     fg_color() {
       if [ "$1" -lt 8 ]; then
         printf '\33[3%sm' "$1"
       elif [ "$1" -lt 16 ]; then
         printf '\33[9%sm' "$(( $1 - 8 ))"
       else
         printf '\33[38;5;%sm' "$1"
       fi
     }
     # and so on.
esac
```